# ASP.NET: data sent throug PushStreamContent is received with delay

Tags: c#, asp.net, server-sent-events

I use the `PushStreamContent` class in ASP.NET for implementing SSE server.

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Get(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = request.CreateResponse();
        response.Content =
                new PushStreamContent(new Action<Stream, HttpContent,                    TransportContext>(OnStreamAvailable),
                    "text/event-stream");     
        return response;
    }
    private void OnStreamAvailable(Stream stream, HttpContent httpContent, TransportContext context)
    {
        streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream) { AutoFlush = true };
    }
    public IHttpActionResult Post(JoinRoomFormViewModel vm)
    {
        streamWriter.WriteLine("data:smth\n");
    }
```

This is an approximate example of usage.

But when the first event is sent client does not receive this data. Status of GET query (which using EventSource for connecting) changes from Waiting to Content Download.

When the second event is sent client receives data sent on the first event. Etc

Sometimes client receives two events at once (latest and previous) but next time nothing receive again.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How are you storing the connected clients?

Comment: @BhushanFirake created in example StreamWriter store into other object in List. WriteLine call from different place. But I think it doesn't matter

Comment: Currently, you are creating Stream each time, writing some response to it and pushing in the stream and closing the stream, delay might be introduced in that.

Comment: @BhushanFirake No, I create stream one time on get query. Ok, I will change code